# Using schtasks from the command line, what parameter will wake the computer from sleep and execute the task

Tags: windows, command-line, scheduled-tasks

The option exists in the UI, but not in the help displayed in the command line.

Comment: Which version of windows/schtasks api do you have?

Comment: All of this should now be able to be replaced by the windows scheduled task cmd-lets in powershell. Specifically the New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet cmd-let should allow us to specify the WakeToRun setting.

Comment: Actually this can be done with a powershell cmdlet (sequence) now: https://superuser.com/questions/1632277/what-is-the-command-line-equivalent-for-toggling-wake-the-computer-to-run-this/

Answer (score 16):

Are you creating a new task via the `schtasks.exe` command line, or updating an existing task?

On Vista, `schtasks.exe` has an `/xml` option for both `/create` and `/query`.  With this XML encoding of the task, you can see the `WakeToRun` node can be set for waking the computer from sleep to run the task:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    ...
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers />
  <Principals>
    ...
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    ...
    <WakeToRun>true</WakeToRun>
    ...
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>myprogram.exe</Command>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

If you need to create a task from the command line that wakes the computer, you could export the basics of the task to XML, modify this XML to add `WakeToRun`, then re-import this XML definition.  You can do this two ways:

1. In the Task Scheduler UI, select "Wake the computer to run this task", right-click on the task and `Export...` to XML.  You can then re-import this file on another machine (see below), and Wake-To-Run will be set.  or,
2. Via the command line, create a task with the basics set (action, time, etc).  Then, export the XML, programatically add the `WakeToRun` node (via XSLT or search/replace), then re-import this updated XML:

   schtasks.exe /create /tn  /xml MyTask.xml /f

Comment: Win 10 built-in tasks like `\Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\Reboot_AC` can only be updated from under the SYSTEM account, so use `psexec.exe -i -s schtasks ...`

Answer (score 8):

In step 2 the command line; `schtasks.exe /create /tn /xml MyTask.xml /f`
This may kick an error that says;
Invalid syntax. Mandatory option 'tn' is missing.

`/tn` needs a name. This should be

```
schtasks.exe /create /tn MyTask /xml "C:\MyTask.xml" /f
```

And if you have or want a space in the name, you can use;

```
schtasks.exe /create /tn "My Task With Spaces" /xml "C:\My Task With Spaces.xml" /f
```

Hope this helps...