# How to pass arguments from a java application to a windows Time Scheduler?

Tags: java

I want to pass arguments to Windows Time Scheduler using java application

So i open Scheduler

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c " + "%windir%\\system32\\taskschd.msc /s");
```

Now  create a simple task . How can i pass arguments programmatically :

[image]

For example i need to pass the following

- Program script: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe
- Add arguments: -jar c:\abc\ab.jar
- Start in: c:\abc

Comment: You want to have a java application pass arguments to another java aplication, or you just want to pass arguments to one application when you run it?

Comment: I want to pass arguments from Java application to a Windows TASK Scheduler

Comment: @AndreiVasilev windows 7?

Comment: Yes sir, it is Windows 7

Answer (score 2):

Don't do it through `cmd` (command - line). Use [ITaskService COM interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381832%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for managing tasks (create, modify, delete). In Java use [Com4J](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jcom/) interface to Windows COM.

But if you still would like to use command - line, use [Windows Powershell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj150476%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for this.

Last way to do this is to create Task Scheduler XML-based file (in Java). Those are XML-s conforming to the [Task Scheduler Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383609%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and are stored in `%SystemRoot%\Tasks` or `%SystemRoot%\System32\Tasks`.

Create code is up to you, especially creating .xml with windows task is quick-and-easy for simple test. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I don't fully understand the question, but I tried my best. This works for me.

```
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar c:\application.jar args");
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Schtasks](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772785%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) command line utility to add tasks. Also, see this question about specifying start folder: [Specifying "start-in" directory in schtasks command in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020023/specifying-start-in-directory-in-schtasks-command-in-windows)