# scheduling task from the command line + windows7 + spaces + arguments

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to become familliar with add task to task scheduler via the command prompt. I seem to be having difficuly with spaces.

This command works successfully in creating a task:

```
schtasks /create /tn \Daily\SOTask /tr "C:\Users\User Name\FolerWhereScriptIs\vbsScript.vbs" /sc daily /mo 1 /st 08:50
SUCCESS: The scheduled task "\Daily\SOTask" has successfully been created.
```

However, when I open the properties of this task in task scheduler i see in:
**Program/script:** C:\Users\User 
**Add arguments(optional):** Name\FolerWhereScriptIs\vbsScript.vbs 
**Start in(optional):** empty

this is obviously not what I want. ideally I would like:
**Program/script:** C:\Windows\System32\WScript.exe 
**Add arguments(optional):** "C:\Users\User Name\FolerWhereScriptIs\vbsScript.vbs" 
**Start in(optional):** C:\Users\User Name\FolerWhereScriptIs\

**How do I achive this from the command line?**

This lists all tasks in the `Daily` folder (so I can see the one I jst created)

```
schtasks /query /TN Daily\
```

**NOTE:** To get this far I ahve gotten help for [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/cc772785%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#BKMK_create) and [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/7cbfcf5f-9f7e-4639-8486-6a01e6cb0006/schtasksexe-to-query-within-a-task-scheduler-library-folder?forum=winservergen)

**EDIT1** I found help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1020730/2392358) and it mentions using a `/V1` flag but todate I cannot get to work. Another Option would be to use XML, whcih I will investigate again. For now I will use the command for setting up my schedule and then go into task scheduler to set the `Start in(optional):` in directory.

Comment: You can use single quotes within the command line, with the whole thing including command line arguments (if any) wrapped in double quotes: `/tr "'C:\Windows\System32\WScript.exe' 'C:\Users\User Name\FolerWhereScriptIs\vbsScript.vbs'"`. Display it in list mode: `schtasks /query /tn \Daily\SOTask /v /fo list`.

Comment: I don't see a way to set the working directory, not without a full XML definition. It may be easier to add a command-line argument to your script that sets the target directory.

Comment: @eryksun tks i think you are right I have reflected this in my edit1 above