# How to set task scheduler's arguments from Power Shell

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

I want to set "Add arguments" in the task scheduler. 
Because we have a lot of windows servers and have to set add arguments on each server.
I know it has to manage command for task scheduler "tasks" but I don't know how to add only "Add arguments". 
I want to know the command that can do what I want to do (first sentence).
Please ask me anything what you want to know about this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Task scheduler administration is better on-topic in ServerFault. That being said, take a look at scheduler's [XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383609(v=vs.85).aspx) schema.

Comment: Please give us a more detailed description of the problem. Thx

Comment: @vonPryz You could have provided [a link to Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/). New users haven't necessarily heard about it.

Comment: Please provide further details of the issue

Comment: In  PowerShell, I'd use cmdlets from `ScheduledTasks` and `PSScheduledJob` modules   rather than `schtasks.exe`.

Comment: I don't want to set task's arguments manually because it takes long time so I need to make bat file.However I am not sure about how to set task's arguments from command.

Also I confuse about PowerShell and command prompt..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn by example (copied & pasted from an open **elevated** `cmd` window; note that `^^>` is my *admin* command prompt):

```
^^> schtasks /query /TN SO_31969962 /V /FO LIST | findstr /R /C:"^Task To Run:" /C:"Start In"
Task To Run:                          D:\bat\SO\31969962.bat "1 st" second
Start In:                             D:\bat\SO\files

^^> schtasks /change /TN "\SO_31969962" /TR "D:\bat\SO\31969962.bat \"first\" second"
SUCCESS: The parameters of scheduled task "\SO_31969962" have been changed.

^^> schtasks /query /TN SO_31969962 /V /FO LIST | findstr /R /C:"^Task To Run:" /C:"Start In"
Task To Run:                          D:\bat\SO\31969962.bat "first" second
Start In:                             N/A

^^>
```

Here the `Task To Run: …` line corresponds to

[image: edit action]

Unfortunately, `schtasks.exe` fails in specifying “start-in” directory as you can see in above example (read entire thread of [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1020023/3439404), google for `schtasks start in directory`).

Following PowerShell code snippet changes *both* `Arguments` and `WorkingDirectory`:

```
$Task = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskPath '\' -TaskName 'SO_31969962'
$Task.Actions[0].Arguments        = 'bubu "foo bar"'
$Task.Actions[0].WorkingDirectory = '"D:\bat\Unusual Names"'
Set-ScheduledTask -InputObject $Task | Out-Null
```

**Edit**: following *commented* batch script shows possible approach of how-to construct a valid PowerShell one-line command (no need to run an existing `.ps1` script):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

    rem related to D:\PShell\SO\41677069_ScheduledTask_Admin.ps1

    rem show current parameters of a task (before change) 
schtasks /query /TN "\SO_31969962" /V /FO LIST | findstr /R /C:"^Task To Run:" /C:"^Start In"

    rem set auxiliary variables (note properly escaped inner double quotes)
set "_taskGet=$Task = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskPath '\' -TaskName 'SO_31969962'"
set "_taskArg=$Task.Actions[0].Arguments = '\""foo bar\"" bubu'"
set "_taskDir=$Task.Actions[0].WorkingDirectory = '\""D:\odds and ends\""'"
set "_taskSet=Set-ScheduledTask -InputObject $Task"

    rem apply auxiliary variables (used merely to keep next line readable)
PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -command "%_taskGet%;%_taskArg%;%_taskDir%;%_taskSet%"

    rem show current parameters of a task (after change)
schtasks /query /TN "\SO_31969962" /V /FO LIST | findstr /R /C:"^Task To Run:" /C:"^Start In"
```

**Result** (read `powershell /?` or [`Get-Help 'about_powershell.exe' -ShowWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe); read also [about_Execution_Policies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies)):

```
^^> powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "D:\PShell\SO\41677069_ScheduledTask_Admin.ps1"

^^> D:\bat\SO\41677069_ScheduledTask_Admin.bat
Task To Run:                          D:\bat\SO\31969962.bat bubu "foo bar"
Start In:                             "D:\bat\Unusual Names"

TaskPath                                       TaskName                          State
--------                                       --------                          -----
\                                              SO_31969962                       Disabled


Task To Run:                          D:\bat\SO\31969962.bat "foo bar" bubu
Start In:                             "D:\odds and ends"

^^>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer !!

Comment: I will try to use power shell cuz start in parameter is not work in command prompt.

Comment: @tekun answer updated: command prompt/batch script example

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion !!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to modify the task action, not the task itself:

```
# Retrieve task
$Task = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "myScheduledTask"

# Retrieve action, modify argument
$Task.Actions[0] = "new arguments string go here"

# Update task
Set-ScheduledTask $Task
```

Comment: Thank you !
Also can I set arguments of tasks using command prompt?