# How to add a value to "start-in" entry of task scheduler via command line

Tags: windows, command-line, window, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

Below is the task scheduler named "once only" that I am creating via command line. I want to add a value to "start-in (optional)". How can I do that?

```
SCHTASKS /create  /tn "once only" /tr "\"c:\Users\" -v abc -br sbr" /sc ONCE /sd 12/29/2014 /st 12:00
```

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: Here's a post about the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020023/specifying-start-in-directory-in-schtasks-command-in-windows