# schtasks how to specify lauch directory

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I need to setup a Window sheduled task passing in the lauch folder,
but looking at the official documentation i can't find how to do that.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357(v=vs.85).aspx

In the Windows Task panel it is a field named "Start in"

This is my actual command

```
schtasks /create /tn "LogicalDOC backup simple" /tr "C:\LogicalDOC-btool3\backup.bat" /sc daily /st 02:00:00
```

Actually this command doesn't work because it must be executed from folder C:\LogicalDOC-btool3

Here is an image of the Task Action properties that actually work, but my need is to setup it from command line or by using something different (VB script or Powershell script)

[image]

**UPDATE:**
I tried to create the task using the /V1 option and I have to say that the working directory (Start in) has been populated, only that the system required me username and password of the user.
I've followed the suggestion of this post
[Specifying the running directory for Scheduled Tasks using schtasks.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447774/specifying-the-running-directory-for-scheduled-tasks-using-schtasks-exe)

I'd like to know if it's possible to specify, during task creation, to execute by the current user without passing it in the launch options, or if it's possible to run the task as SYSTEM user

Comment: cant you use `pushd C:\LogicalDOC-btool3` on top of the backup.bat ?

Comment: No, currently it's not possible

Comment: are you able to create another bat then schedule execution of these last one ?

Comment: Not, and in any case would not solve the problem.

Comment: why are you so categoric ? yes it can solve this issue ...

Comment: Sorry @Kayasax, I didn't want to be rude, but in my option that would not solve the problem. The fact is that I can't specify in the file .bat the run folder, nor I can put in it a change directory (cd).

Comment: if you could have created the bat, you were able to do something like `cd c:\your_path; call backup.bat`

Comment: You're right, your suggestion works (I've tried on my Windows 8.1), but I have to check 2 things: 
1) If it works also on Windows server 2008 R2 standard
2) if I can set the directory information in a dynamic way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you have created the task in the UI ( your screenshot), you can export it's properties to XML (right clik, export).
Then you van import this xml using `schtasks /create /XML path/to/taskprop.xml ...`