# Python Scripts running through Task Scheduler not creating .csv files

Tags: python, csv, scheduled-tasks

I have several python scripts that are running from the Windows Task Scheduler.  When I execute the scripts manually, they create .csv files inside of a folder that I use for various reports.  When I run the scripts through task scheduler, they will run, but they do not create the .csv files.  I have them setup to run even when I am not logged on, and to wake the computer to run.  Does anyone know why the .csv files are not being created?

Comment: Are you using relative paths for your filenames?

Comment: Kind of curious why I got the down vote.  Inside the python script yes.  I am using relative files names.  The .csv's are inside the same folder as the Python scripts.  Here is an example: `with open('myFile.csv', mode='wb') as F:
    F.write(output.encode('ascii', 'replace'))
print("Done.")`

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your question is lacking information to diagnose the issue. I happen to have guessed right here, but others may have felt you should have provided that info up-front.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When running a task with Windows Task Scheduler, your 'current working directory', the location from which relative paths are resolved, is different from when you run a script manually.

Either [set the current directory for the task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447774/specifying-the-running-directory-for-scheduled-tasks-using-schtasks-exe), or don't use relative paths.

Comment: Just tested that, and it worked.  Thank you.