# c# exe throwing error only when run through task scheduler

Tags: c#-2.0

I have an exe that developed on visual studio.
When we run it on the server, it will execute with out any issues.
But when I tried to execute it through Task scheduler, it is not running.
Please find the below error message from event viewer.
Please help me to resolve the issue

```
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException
Stack:
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32, System.String)
   at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(System.String, System.String, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.Create()
   at CentralMarketTransfer.HEB.CentralMarketTransfer.util.SimpleLogging.LogMessageToFile(System.String)
   at CentralMarketTransfer.HEB.CenteralMarketTransfer.main.ProjectMain.Main(System.String[])
```

Comment: My psychic powers tell me you run the task under an account that does not have access to the folder.

Comment: Or mine tell me, it's a relative path with a different base directory.

Answer (score 4):

Try to explicitly set the start directory for the task. You can set in Task Scheduler.

```
Select Task -> Right Click -> Properties -> Actions Tab -> Select Action -> Edit -> Start in (optional)
```

Answer (score 1):

To me it seems that the current running directory is different when the exe is executed directly and when running through the task scheduler.

For reference:

[What is the default working directory for a scheduled task in Windows 2008 R2?](https://serverfault.com/questions/609651/what-is-the-default-working-directory-for-a-scheduled-task-in-windows-2008-r2)

[Specifying the running directory for Scheduled Tasks using schtasks.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447774/specifying-the-running-directory-for-scheduled-tasks-using-schtasks-exe)