# Task Scheduler from command line

Tags: batch-file, command-line, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I'm trying to do the equivalent of this (exported directly from task scheduler) xml file from command line.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.3" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2014-04-15T15:17:02.4785276</Date>
    <Author>~COMPUTER_NAME~\~USER_NAME~</Author>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <EventTrigger>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <Subscription>&lt;QueryList&gt;&lt;Query Id="0" Path="Security"&gt;&lt;Select Path="Security"&gt;*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing'] and EventID=4625]]&lt;/Select&gt;&lt;/Query&gt;&lt;/QueryList&gt;</Subscription>
      <ValueQueries>
        <Value name="IpAddress">Event/EventData/Data[@Name='IpAddress']</Value>
      </ValueQueries>
    </EventTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>~COMPUTER_NAME~\~USER_NAME~</UserId>
      <LogonType>Password</LogonType>
      <RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>true</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>false</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>false</DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>
    <UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>false</UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT1H</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>~Location_Of_Batch_Script~</Command>
      <Arguments>$(IpAddress)</Arguments>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

Is this even possible?

The goal is to have a batch script run as administrator when a specific event (4625 - Failed RD connection attempt) which will manage incoming brute force attacks. This command is needed for the installer script to add this to the task scheduler.

It needs to be run as administrator, but is there a way to do that without making people put their username and password in (or is that not even needed)?

Also, Would this .xml file or the command line variant be supported across most versions of Windows? It is intended for use on Windows Server OS's.

Answer (score 0):

If you type `schtasks /create /?` it will tell you what to do. You'll need a password at some stage. If using service or System account you put the password in when creating (if not an elevated admin).

LocalService Account
The LocalService account is a predefined local account used by the service control manager. This account is not recognized by the security subsystem, so you cannot specify its name in a call to the LookupAccountName function. It has minimum privileges on the local computer and presents anonymous credentials on the network. The name of the account in all locales is NT AUTHORITY\LOCALSERVICE. This account does not have a password.

NetworkService Account
The NetworkService account is a predefined local account used by the service control manager. This account is not recognized by the security subsystem, so you cannot specify its name in a call to the LookupAccountName function. It has minimum privileges on the local computer and acts as the computer on the network. The name of the account in all locales is NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE. This account does not have a password

LocalSystem Account
The LocalSystem account is a predefined local account used by the service control manager. This account is not recognized by the security subsystem, so you cannot specify its name in a call to the LookupAccountName function. It has extensive privileges on the local computer, and acts as the computer on the network. Its token includes the NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM and BUILTIN\Administrators SIDs; these accounts have access to most system objects. The name of the account in all locales is .\LocalSystem. The name, LocalSystem or ComputerName\LocalSystem can also be used. This account does not have a password.